# StringBuilder improperly reversing a filename

Tags: java, string, reverse, stringbuilder

I have a StringBuilder used to simply reverse and return a string. The string in question is a filename: "server_1.8.2_java_8.jar" (this will vary).

When I reverse the string and return it, it becomes "sre_.._aa8jra._vj281rve". I've used some variations of this (as well as regular sentences like "Reverse this string") and I get the same result.

However, if I directly assign the string inside the method it's reversed in (rather than taking it as a parameter and performing [some operations](http://pastebin.com/jt7U6idi) on it), it seems to work properly.

Test method code in case it helps:

```
static String parseJarfileName(String jarLocation) {
            if(jarLocation == null)
                    return ""; // path to jar location is empty,
                                       // return so stuff doesn't get messed up
            String jarfileName = ""; // name of the .jar server executable
            for(int i = jarLocation.length(); jarLocation.charAt(i - 1) != '/'; i --) {
                    // read the string backwards until a / is found,
                    // signaling that the jarfile name has ended
                    // as this is done, concatenate the characters of the jarfile name
                    jarfileName += jarLocation.charAt(i - 1);
                    jarfileName.trim();
                    // the jarfile name will be backwards here, so reverse it
                    String str = new StringBuilder(jarfileName).reverse().toString();
                    jarfileName = str;
            }
            return jarfileName;
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String filePath = "/Users/John/Desktop/server/server_1.8.2_java_8.jar";
    String fileName = parseJarfileName(filePath);
    System.out.println(fileName);
}

// written by 2xedo: twitter.com/2xedo
```

This code prints "sre_.._aa8jra._vj281rve" to the console.

Comment: Please post the relevant portion of the code in your post directly.

Comment: Also, consider posting a small self-contained program that tests your code and demonstrates for us with an array of test Strings and a for loop the error that you're seeing.

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: @Pshemo I was expecting the string jarfileName, which is "raj.8_avaj_2.8.1_revres", to be "server_1.8.2_java_8.jar". I just have a backwards filename and I need to reverse it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I am not mistaken you are looking for something like

```
public static String parseJarfileName(String jarLocation) {
    if (jarLocation == null)
        return ""; 
    return jarLocation.substring(jarLocation.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
}
```

Or maybe little more readable

```
public static String parseJarfileName(String jarLocation) {
    if (jarLocation == null)
        return ""; 
    return new File(jarLocation).getName();
}
```

You can also use `Path` which is newer (and in most cases preferred) version of `File`

```
return Paths.get(jarLocation).getFileName().toString();
```

Comment: I feel really stupid for not knowing about this. It does exactly what I need, thank you.

Comment: @2xedo You are welcome. Next time also try to describe what your code is suppose to do, not just want it does wrong. This makes helping you easier and you are avoiding [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) :)

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is return the filename, why not just do `jarLocation.substring(jarLocation.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, jarLocation.length);`

You'll probably have to do a bit more to handle edge cases and whatnot, but this should give you exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: `jarLocation.length` is redundant, `substring(jarLocation.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)` is enough.

Answer (score 1):

You are reversing the filename each and every iteration.

```
r
ra
arj
jra.
.arj8
//...
```

Move the `reverse()` code after the end of the `for` loop.

```
    }  // end of for loop
    // the jarfile name will be backwards here, so reverse it
    String str = new StringBuilder(jarfileName).reverse().toString();
    jarfileName = str;

    return jarfileName;
}
```

Also, it doesn't seem to matter here in a filename without spaces, but

```
jarfileName.trim();
```

is useless without assigning the returned value to something.  Use

```
jarfileName = jarfileName.trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove this:

```
String str = new StringBuilder(jarfileName).reverse().toString();
jarfileName = str;
```

and all seems to be fine.